# IdentityServer4.Validation.TokenRequestValidator: Invalid authorization code

Tags: identityserver4, asp.net-core-5.0

I am using Identity Server 4 With Microsoft Blazor application. Authentication process works fine in local. But after deploying changes in azure it was working fine before one week. Suddenly it's started giving some errors and stuck on https://websiteurl.com/signin-oidc page. After checking identity server log I found this error

> IdentityServer4.Validation.TokenRequestValidator: Invalid authorization code

Some times it's working and some times getting above error. More than 50% of time i am getting above error.

I tried following code generate custom codeVerifier and add before redirecting to identity server.

```
if (context.ProtocolMessage.RequestType == OpenIdConnectRequestType.Authentication)

{
    // generate code_verifier
    var codeVerifier = CryptoRandom.CreateUniqueId(32);

    // store codeVerifier for later use
    context.Properties.Items.Remove(CODE_VERIFIER_KEY);
    context.Properties.Items.Add(CODE_VERIFIER_KEY, codeVerifier);

    Logger.Log(LogLevel.Information, CODE_VERIFIER_KEY + ": " + codeVerifier);

    // create code_challenge
    string codeChallenge;
    using (var sha256 = SHA256.Create())
    {
        var challengeBytes = sha256.ComputeHash(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(codeVerifier));
        codeChallenge = Base64Url.Encode(challengeBytes);
    }

    // add code_challenge and code_challenge_method to request
    context.ProtocolMessage.Parameters.Remove(CODE_CHALLENGE_KEY);
    context.ProtocolMessage.Parameters.Remove(CODE_CHALLENGE_METHOD_KEY);
    Logger.Log(LogLevel.Information, CODE_CHALLENGE_KEY + ": " + codeChallenge);
    context.ProtocolMessage.Parameters.Add(CODE_CHALLENGE_KEY, codeChallenge);
    context.ProtocolMessage.Parameters.Add(CODE_CHALLENGE_METHOD_KEY, "S256");
}
```

```
OnAuthorizationCodeReceived = (context) =>
{
    // context.Options.
    //Add claim if they are
    //var claims = new List<Claim> {   new Claim(ClaimTypes.Role, "Provider")  };
    //var appIdentity = new ClaimsIdentity(claims);

    //context.Principal.AddIdentity(appIdentity);

    // only when authorization code is being swapped for tokens
    // only when authorization code is being swapped for tokens

    Logger.Log(LogLevel.Information, "OnAuthorizationCodeReceived - " + context.TokenEndpointRequest.Parameters);

    if (context.TokenEndpointRequest?.GrantType == OpenIdConnectGrantTypes.AuthorizationCode)
    {

        // get stored code_verifier, This if condition is never gets executed
        if (context.Properties.Items.TryGetValue(CODE_VERIFIER_KEY, out var codeVerifier))
        {
            // add code_verifier to token request
            context.TokenEndpointRequest.Parameters.Add(CODE_VERIFIER_KEY, codeVerifier);
        }
    }

    return Task.CompletedTask;
},
```

Comment: Do you have multiple instances of the backend client application deployed?

Comment: @ToreNestenius Yes,

Found same and moved to single instance from multiple instance and it's working fine now. Thanks

Comment: You will have problem with this when you have multiple instances, as the same instance must also be the same one through out the entire authorization code flow.

Answer (score -1):

In order to scale up identity Server 4:

1. Make Configuration and Grant store persistent.
2. Use a shared certificate for signing key and validate it.

   ```
   services.AddIdentityServer()
       .AddConfigurationStore(options =>
       {
           options.ConfigureDbContext = builder =>
               builder.UseSqlServer(connectionString,
                   sql => sql.MigrationsAssembly(migrationsAssembly));
       })
       .AddOperationalStore(options =>
       {
           options.ConfigureDbContext = builder =>
           builder.UseSqlServer(connectionString,
               sql => sql.MigrationsAssembly(migrationsAssembly));
           // this enables automatic token cleanup. this is optional.
           options.EnableTokenCleanup = true;
           options.TokenCleanupInterval = 3600; // interval in seconds (default is 3600)
       })
       .AddSigningCredential(LoadCertificate())
       .AddValidationKey(LoadCertificate());
   ```
3. Add data protection and keep the keys shared (either in Redis or Filestore or Blob storage). Given example for using Redis:

   ```
   var connectionMultiplexer = ConnectionMultiplexer.Connect(config["Redis:Connection"]);
   services.AddDataProtection()
       .PersistKeysToStackExchangeRedis(connectionMultiplexer, "DataProtection-Keys")
       .SetDefaultKeyLifetime(TimeSpan.FromDays(90))
       .SetApplicationName("AppHostName");
   ```